# npm compiling warning (Unexpected template string expression no-template-curly-in-string)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

npm compiling warning (Unexpected template string expression no-template-curly-in-string)

```js
import React from 'react';

const Card = ({name, email, id }) => {
    return (
       <div className='tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5'>
          <img alt='robots' src={'https://robohash.org/${id}?200x200'} />
          <div>
             <h2>{name}</h2>
             <p>{email}</p>
          </div>
       </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img alt='robots' src={'https://robohash.org/${id}?200x200'} />
```

change to

```
<img alt='robots' src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?200x200`} />
```

you should use ``. Because you type a variable (id) that comes with props.

Answer (score 0):

I bootstraped a pristine react app with the CLI to try things out. With npm@3 flattening it should work right away. With npm@2, you'll probably have to install some deps globally since fast-eslint isn't smart enough to add relative reference inside the lookup array for modules loading (it should add ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules to the array).